# how to generate s3 style access/secret key using java

Tags: java, amazon-s3, bouncycastle, hmacsha1

I am trying to generate access keys and secret keys in the same fashion as S3 using java but am having some trouble.

As a starting point I am looking at this [bouncy castle example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/RSASignatureGeneration.htm) , I have this code up and running but am not sure of two things 1) how to set it up to use the same key generation as s3 which uses HMAC-SHA1 as outlined [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?RESTAuthentication.html) and 2) how to get the friendly public/private key strings out for the the user.

You may have guessed I am new to java encryption and the bouncy castle libraries, however I did find JCEKeyGenerator.HMACSHA1 in the bc docs but am unable to find an example of its use.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to make use of `javax.crypto.KeyGenerator` to create the `AWSAccessKeyId` and the `AWSSecretAccessKey`:

```
javax.crypto.KeyGenerator generator = javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.getInstance("HMACSHA1");
generator.init(120);
byte[] awsAccessKeyId = generator.generateKey().getEncoded();
generator.init(240);
byte[] awsSecretAccessKey = generator.generateKey().getEncoded();
```

Then, you'll want to base64 encode the bytes (this uses MimeUtility from mail.jar):

```
final ByteArrayOutputStream encoded = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
final OutputStream encoder = javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility.encode(encoded, "base64");
encoder.write(awsAccessKeyId);
encoder.flush();
encoder.close();
String accessKeyId = new String(encoded.toByteArray(), encoding).replaceAll("[\\r\\n]", "");
```